# If row is null else

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a column named "votes" which have the value "NULL" when the row first gets created. At the end of the day, I will add the votes coming from another table and put all the votes into the correct row. The problem is that if it is the first time the row gets votes, I will have to write `SET votes = '$votes'` but if it already has votes I will have to write `SET votes = votes + '$votes'`. Is there any easy way to detect if it is null or if it has an value?

Comment: Do you want to add new votes to previous one ? So it increase each time

Comment: `votes + '$votes'` would try to add a string to a number. Just use `votes + $votes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**Ifnull**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)

```
SET votes = IFNULL(votes, 0) + votes
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the ifnull MYSQL function, the SQL will be like

```
UPDATE .... SET votes = IFNULL(votes, 0) + votes
```

Answer (score 2):

try this, `COALESCE` or `IFNULL`.

```
SET votes = COALESCE(votes, 0) + '$votes'
```

if the value of votes is `null`, it will be converted to 0 other wise retain the original value and added it to your `$votes`.

Answer (score 2):

**Initialise the field to `0` instead of `NULL`.**

It makes sense for something to start off with no votes.

In fact, I'd make this column `NOT NULL`!